# How to execute a local test with robot framework inside docker and save output into host

Tags: docker, robotframework

I created a docker image from a Dockerfile that has an environment to to run robot framework ready. I want to run a local file using the docker image and save the output of the test locally.

I know I can mount a file when I run an image and execute the test.

```
$ docker create -ti -v /path/to/file/testWithRobot/robottest.robot:/test/robottest.robot dc3dccfee60 robot test/robottest.robot
```

and then I know to save a file from docker is cp

I have 2 problems, I know that as soon as I stop that instance of docker the file gets removed, or better said when I start the mage again is a different instance of it. if I go inside the docker image mounting the file and running the tests I know the output files gets saved in the root

```
Output:  /output.xml
Log:     /log.html
Report:  /report.html
```

how do I save those files output.xml, log.html, and report.xml into the host. I am hoping I can use one command to run tests and save. I hope I explained well enough quite new to docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a container using:

```
docker run --name mytests -v /path/to/file/testWithRobot/robottest.robot:/test/robottest.robot dc3dccfee60 robot test/robottest.robot
```

and grab the contents using the `name` we set:

```
docker cp mytests:/output.xml .
docker cp mytests:/log.html .
docker cp mytests:/report.html .
```

Then you can delete the stopped container with:

```
docker rm mytest
```

Also, using this approach you won't face file permission and ownership issues.

Comment: Thank you but can I ask how to actually run using -name tag? ```unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -name``` I get this when I copy your command and I know of --name but that still doesn't work

Comment: Ouch, it must be `--name`. What's the issue then?

Comment: ```docker run --name mytest -v Desktop/testWithRobot/robottest.robot:/test/robottest.robot dc3dccfee60 robot test/robotest.robot``` I run this command and I get ```[ ERROR ] Parsing 'test/robotest.robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.```

Comment: ```docker run -name mytests -v /path/to/file/testWithRobot/robottest.robot:/test/robottest.robot dc3dccfee60 robot test/robottest.robot```
 this works so the mount does work

Comment: Ouch spelling mistake in file name/ this is awkward, that you for your help